# Why would a dog bark when it's afraid?

Tags: dogs, behavior

A stray dog used to bark at the locals in the street. However each time whenever the person who is barked at approached the dog, it would run away cowardly.

Why would the dog bark when it's actually afraid of the person?

Comment: It's like the pretend-tough-guy acting tough before he shy away from the real fight

Answer (score 2):

It's more or less what @Huangism says in his/her comment - the dog is acting tough, saying "Stay away from me! I'll hurt you if you come close!" Trying to keep people away from him/her.
So the barking is a fear response... just like the running away when people *do* come close.

The dog may also feel (s)he is defending his/her territory, but actually be afraid of a real fight. With a stray dog, you never know what they've been through, they may have very bad experiences with humans :-( ... that only a lot of tender loving care can heal.

Either way it's a pro-active threat that (s)he is too afraid to execute.

Answer (score 1):

When competing in the wild, animals will challenge before they fight. That's because fighting is inherently risky - even if they 'win' they might be damaged, and be less effective as a result.

So what'll normally happen is when there's a point of contention, they'll start by trying to convince the opposition that it isn't worth it. Exerting dominance by barking or growling, in the hopes that that'll avoid a fight, and they'll still get to keep whatever it was they were about to fight over. The more you're afraid of something, the more you need to convince it not to mess with you.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that even if the dog's barking isn't backed up instantly by action, if you continue to approach a fearful stray animal, it might consider you a big enough threat to attack even if its normal reaction is to flee.

Animals that are afraid don't always think straight, too. Try not to constantly call the dog's 'bluff', or it'll become afraid that you're not respecting its safety and might react violently.